# Default to specific filter option extjs 4.1.3

Tags: javascript, xml, extjs

I have a grid that returns various types of data with filtering activated. One column is filtered based on three distinct options.

I need to load the grid with filtering enabled on one specific option. How Do I load a grid with one specific option already filtered?

```
var columns = [{
                text: 'Title',
                width: 260,
                dataIndex: 'Title',
                filterable: true
            }, {
                text: 'Description',
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'Description',
                filter: {
                    type: 'string'
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Modified',
                width: 90,
                dataIndex: 'Modified',
                xtype: 'datecolumn',
                format: 'm/d/Y',
                filter: true
            }, {
                text: 'Status',
                width: 90,
                dataIndex: 'TopicStateValue',
                filter: {
                    type: 'list',
                    options: ['Open/Current', 'Archived/Closed', 'Hold']
                }
            }];
```

I need to load the grid with `Open/Current` items set to active.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just perform the filtering on the store.
If you want to perform filtering in the background that is usually the way to go.

Another option is to activate the filter and the set it's value.
See your other question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/45380759/333492) for details on how to do that.