# Extjs 4.1.3 button that sets active filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, extjs, extjs4.1

I want to add a button to the toolbar that automatically sets a filter as active and then subsequently filters the data. I have tried using the `setActive()` function for `Ext 4.1.3` but that function is not being recognized.

[fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/238v)

**Code**

```
var openButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Open Topics',
            handler: function () {
                grid[uniqueId].filters.setActive('Open/Current');
            }
        });

...
var columns = [{
    text: 'Status',
    width: 100,
    dataIndex: 'TopicStateValue',
    filter: {
        type: 'list',
        options: ['Open/Current', 'Archived/Closed', 'Hold']
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

The setActive method can't be found in the location you look for it.
You're trying to execute setActive on a list of filters, but the actual function can only be executed once you have found the specific filter object.

In your example code (the Fiddle is of no use as you skipped the column in question there) you would get the filter first like this:

```
var filter = grid[uniqueId].filters.getFilter('TopicStateValue');
filter.setActive(true);
```

However activating the filter doesn't do what you expect it to do. It will merely enable the filter UI element in the filters bar.
To execute said filter automatically after enabling it you need to set the Value for that filter:

```
filter.setValue('Open/Current');
```

If you're not using the filters bar or don't want to show this particular filter dropdown to the user at all, you're better off filtering the store directly:

```
var store = grid[uniqueId].getStore();
store.filterBy(function(item) {
    return item.TopicStateValue == 'Open/Current';
});
```

Comment: Also note worthy that `grid[uniqueId].filters.getFilter('TopicStateValue')` will only work on ExtJS 4.2.2+ if you haven't activated it before using the Column menu.

Comment: Oh how great would it be if the ExtJS documentation would actually include such remarks about problems fixed in later versions.

Comment: Starting with 5, you have access to the Release Notes that shows all bug fixes, etc.
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1.1/guides/whats_new/release_notes.html